# Error: "Unable to resolve module `./InitialWindowSafeAreaInsets`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a project in React Native. I've finished the coding and after this, I have to install some dependencies such as react-native-screens, react-native-vector-icons, etc.

It appears to me: "Unable to resolve module `./InitialWindowSafeAreaInsets` from `node_modules\\react-native-safe-area-context\\src\\index.tsx`. Below there is what appear in the Metro Bundler of my localhost:

```
LOGGED IN AS
INFO
16:02
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
INFO
16:02
Tunnel ready.
ERROR
16:03
Unable to resolve "./InitialWindowSafeAreaInsets" from "node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\index.tsx"
ERROR
16:03
Building JavaScript bundle: error
```

I know that I could simply install react-native-safe-area-context, but due the fact I haven't found any issue about this neither here nor in GitHub, I've preferred to be conservative and share with you the issue, instead of install the package and it becomes a snowball.

Maybe the solution is really install react-native-safe-area-context package, but I prefer to share before, because maybe anyone is being the same issue and could help with further information.

Later, I installed the react-native-safe-area-context package, and it remains the same error. How could I solve this issue?

Comment: generally we do not allow screenshots of code and error messages since it's not indexable and searchable. Please copy and paste it here, and remove the screenshot.

Comment: @Samuel Liew, I've already fixed the issue. Regards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This problem occurs with the following combinations:

- expo@3.13.1
- react-native-safe-area-context@0.6.0

Expo asks for react-native-safe-area-context@0.6.0, but please ignore it.
Actually, you need @0.7.3.

(Expo send 'InitialWindowSafeAreaInsets', but @0.6.0 cannot receive it. @0.6.0 can only receive 'InitialSafeAreaInsets'. Who Moved My 'Window'?)

so, please try this way.

```
yarn add react-native-safe-area-context@0.7.3
```

Answer (score 1):

For some people met the issue must to change resolver in metro config file to have 
'ts' extension ...

```
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    /* resolver options */
    sourceExts: ['jsx','js','tsx', 'ts'] //add here
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```